# My task was to transfer the string length in parenthesis(javascript)

Tags: javascript, string

```
const smth = str => {
      const test = str.split(",")
                      .map(x => {
                          return x + '(' + x.length + ')';
                       })
                       .join(", ");
      return test;
};
```

Expected result was "hello(5),world(5),abra(4),carabfa(7),re(2),wrewer(6),rwer(4)"

Why is it not the best solution to use this piece: `'(' + x.length + ')'`?

Comment: Who says it's not "the best"? What is the _precise_ feedback given (error messages and unexpected results are also feedback!), and what makes the code above "not correct"? On a _modern_ ECMAScript implementation, one _could_ use [string interpolation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals); however, if such is "any better" is largely a preference / style choice. Also, parenthesis really have nothing to do with the question.. it might as well be `'FOO' + x.length + 'BAR'`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is really hard to say what the best solution is.
I would prefer not to use .join() after .map() after .split() while we can use .reduce() like in code here below. It works faster, but was the speed in the req list? Some prefers readability and it is more about style choise, indeed.

```js
const str = 'hello,world,abra,carabfa,re,wrewer,rwer'
const str_ = str.split(',').reduce((res, word) => `${res}${res ? ',' : ''}${word}(${word.length})`, '')
console.log(str_)
```